# How can I display Git info on my site in certain environments?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, test-environments

We have a web application under development by a mid-size team. We maintain several environments for development and testing.

A problem I've come up against is not knowing which version of the code is currently on a particular server. We work around this by just re-deploying whenever we're unsure.

Is there any way to include information from Git in (for example) the website footer? Ideally we'd be able to see the latest commit, the branch, and any tags.

Without reinventing the wheel, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You can create a commit hook in git which will write current version number or any other information you need to some file. You can then use information from this file however you want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44458407/7976758